# UIViewController with textField and tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following problem:

I got a UIViewController and it contains a textfield and a tableview. I push the view from another one, so that I got a navigationbar on top. I enabled the edit-button, and navigation also works fine.
What my problem is:
-the edit button is not working. I was looking through here, but I couldn't get it fixed
-when I enter data in to the textfield, the tableview gets the data, reloading is working, but it doesn't show any animation, and no rows are added ...

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[controller insertCostumer:textField.text];

[textField resignFirstResponder];
[tabViewitem reloadData];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:controller.sizeOfNavi+1 inSection:1];
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arr addObject:indexPath];

[tabViewitem insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
return YES;
```

}

This is my textfieldshouldreturn method, I also tried out textfieldshouldendediting and textfielddidendediting and so on :-)
Hope somebody has any clue how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried first insert a row and then reload the table?

Comment: Will do a workaround right now ... setting a flag and editing the whole thing differently ... couldnt figure out how to do it.
Thanks anyways, if somebody finds out something, please let me know.

Comment: @Vanya, yes tried that too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no direct solution but I think I found a useful link for you:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11315-textfieldshouldreturn-not-called-probrem.html

This person has some problems to while calling the 'textFieldShouldReturn' method.

Comment: hmm, the textfieldshouldreturn is beeing called, but the animation as in :" [tabViewitem insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
" is not shown. I do not see the data getting added to the tableview. only when I switch to a different view and back...

Comment: I see that you call 'insertRowsAtIndexPaths' to 'tabViewitem' I can't see where the 'tabViewitem' variable is initialized but here a few checks: - Is the 'tabViewitem' variable an 'IBOutlet UITableView' and is it linked properly. - try to override 'canEditRowAtIndexPath' and returning YES.

Comment: I mage da few adjustments, I will workaround, with custum-made tableviewcells :-) worked out right for me ... will have to look into that issue some other time